# Aleinu After Kiddush Levanah

Tags: maariv, kiddush-levanah, aleinu-leshabeiach

Why is aleinu said twice: once at the end of Maariv, and then again at the end of Kiddush Levanah?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/136/603

Comment: Probably they just used to go out to say Kiddush Levana before Alenu like where many count the Omer, and then people/Siddurim were silly and got confused and thought there has to be a separate Alenu later on. Similarly they would perform a circumcision in Shul right after Kaddish Titkabbel, and then people were silly and thought Alenu was part of the circumcision. You have to remember that Alenu is just a bonus prayer said at the end of whatever is going on. It's not actually part of Shacharit/Maariv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First Because we say:

> שֶׁהֵם מִשְׁתַּחֲוִים לְהֶבֶל וָרִיק
>   וּמִתְפַּלְּלִים אֶל אֵל לֹא יושיע

- That is we are illustrating the Idol worshipers pray to heavenly bodies but we do not. (*[Likutie Maharich,Chelek Beis,Daf Kuf](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41190&st=&pgnum=201)*)
- Aleinu, was written by Yeshouah Ben Nun he was compared to moon. That is the Gemara in [Baba Basra 75a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.75a.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says:

> The face of Moshe was Like the sun,Yeshouah was like the Moon.

Therfore the comparison compels us to say Aleinu at Kiddush Levanah.

Source:[Rite and reason: 1050 Jewish customs and their sources](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14556&hilite=43c916ee-72a9-4130-9cd8-3d94af32af91&st=%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A9+%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%94&pgnum=216)

Comment: Not facing the moon is not lidivrei hakol. The Kneses Hagedolah bringd down to look at the moon while saying the bracha. this indicates that he has no problem with being turned towards it. The Mishnah berurah objects to gazing at the the moon for the bracha  based on the kabbalistic considerations of the Shelah but does not discuss facing towards it. Even though we do not pasken like the Kneses Hagedolah there are many who have the minhag to say kiddush levana while turned towards the moon.

Comment: Also, if the minhag is to be faced towards the moon for birchas halevana it then makes sense that we should declare Aleinu to clarify what we just did. If one faces away, it is sort of obvious that he is not praying to the moon!

Comment: Are you quoting the likutei mahariah as saying one should not face the moon while saying birchas halevana?

Comment: Actually, Likutei Maharah implies that we do face the Levanah and that is why it is important to say Aleinu afterwards. I have yet to find a source that says not to be facing the moon when saying Birchas HaLevana!

Comment: And I have seen many Talmidei Chachamim and Gedolim who face the moon for it. I have asked Gedolim about this turning away practice and some said they never heard of it and others said it is a new humrah with no real reason in Halacha.

Comment: Sorry, YS, but this new humrah of not facing the moon for kiddush levanah is a pet-peeve of mine and you seemed to imply that it had a source in the maharih. It turns out my Rebbeim are still correct and the implication of all those who I can find who talk about kiddush levanah is that there is no problem with facing it during kiddush levanah. One should just be careful not to bow towards it when he dances by the verse "Just as I dance opposite you etc." and one should only gaze at the moon for a moment before reciting the bracha.

Comment: I heard theno facing thing too it make sence as it does look like we are davenning to the moos

Comment: "I heard" is not how we determine that something is a halacha in Judaism. It makes no sense since the sifrei halacha are only concerned with gazing at the moon and do not mention facing the moon. Also the first purpose of Aleinu would be unnecessary.

Comment: YS, "Rite and Reason" is an English translation of "Sefer Taamei Haminhagim Umekorei Hadinim". I added a link to the page in the original sefer to your answer.